# How to use guava CacheBuilder?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I'd like to use guavas `CacheBuilder`, but cannot find any explicit example how implement this.

The docs state the following code:

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
             public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
               return createExpensiveGraph(key);
             }
           });
```

Question: what is this `createExpensiveGraph(key)` method? Is this a method that returns a `HashMap<Key, Value>` mapping? What do I have to do with the `key` value?

Or could I also just return a `List<String>` in this method not having to use the `key` value in any way?

Comment: See the api of CacheLoader and load method which gives clear meaning of why the method is used? 
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#load(K)

createExpensiveGraph does not return hashMap instead return a object of Graph.

Comment: It's whatever function you're trying to cache the result of.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The idea of the cache is that you usually have this problem:

```
Graph get(Key key) {
    Graph result = get( key );
    if( null == result ) {
        result = createNewGraph( key );
        put( key, result );
    }
    return result;
}
```

plus the usual synchronization issues that you have when you use this code in a multi-threaded environment.

Guava does the boilerplate for you; you just have to implement `createNewGraph()`. The way Java works, this means you have to implement an interface. In this case, the interface is `CacheLoader`.

If you think that the whole cache is a bit like a map, then `CacheLoader` is a callback that gets invoked whenever a key can't be found in the map. The loader will get the key (because it usually contains useful information to create the object that is expected for this key) and it will return the value which `get()` should return in the future.